# typeerror unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float' in python and fusion360

Tags: python, fusion360

I'm trying to get a distance calculated in mm's with a for next loop in python for fusion360.

The calculation gives an error:

> typeerror unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'float'

The calulation is:

```
distance = scale - (scale / 2^ (x/12))
```

I think it has to do with casting to int numbers (although I think it must be possible work with values in milimeters with 2 decimals).
I've tried

```
distance = int(scale - (scale / 2^ (x/12)))
```

and

```
distance = int(scale - (float(scale / 2^ (x/12)) )
```

But all give me the dreaded typeerror....

Who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're looking for `**` instead of `^`.

Comment: `^` is **not** the exponentiation operator in Python. That is the bitwise XOR operation. You want `2 **(x/12)`

Comment: Awsome... totally forgot about that... Gentleman, thank you.